# After setting up git and running the ssh /-T git@/github.com command it says I don't have shell access

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh

I am new to web development and trying to get used to Git and GitHub. After setting up my Git for Windows and using the Git Bash shell, I run the command `ssh -T git@github.com` and get the following message:

> Hi spark! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell >access.

I ran the following command:

`git remote -v` and `git remote show origin`

I get the following message:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I begin to set the repository using this command:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:spark/developercourse`

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I have added my public key to GitHub successfully. I just want to connect using public keys and access my repository on GitHub. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The message that you don't have shell access is normal and expected.  If you see that message, it means that you are properly authenticated with the given user and pushes over SSH with the same key will use that account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized the local folder as a repository? Try running `git init`.

Comment: Ran the command:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>$ git init
>Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/jasta/.git/ reran the ssh -T git@github.com and still get the GitHub does not allow shell access error

Comment: Just went into directory on local computer that had my files and did `git init`. Everything works fine now. Thank you.